# In android if I have min api 21 does cameraX cover all devices or do I need to maintain a camera1 implementation for older devices?

Tags: android, android-camera

I currently have an app with a minimum api of 21 that has both a camera1 and a camera2 implementation. Based on the following code I select whether to use camera1 or camera2:

```
            val cameraIds = manager.cameraIdList
            for (id in cameraIds) {
                val info = manager.getCameraCharacteristics(id)
                val facing = info.get(CameraCharacteristics.LENS_FACING)!!

                val level = info.get(CameraCharacteristics.INFO_SUPPORTED_HARDWARE_LEVEL)!!
                val hasFullLevel = level == CameraCharacteristics.INFO_SUPPORTED_HARDWARE_LEVEL_FULL

                val syncLatency = info.get(CameraCharacteristics.SYNC_MAX_LATENCY)!!
                val hasEnoughCapability = syncLatency == CameraCharacteristics.SYNC_MAX_LATENCY_PER_FRAME_CONTROL

                // All these are guaranteed by
                // CameraCharacteristics.INFO_SUPPORTED_HARDWARE_LEVEL_FULL, but checking
                // for only the things we care about expands range of devices we can run on.
                // We want:
                //  - Back-facing camera
                //  - Per-frame synchronization (so that exposure can be changed every frame)
                if (facing == CameraCharacteristics.LENS_FACING_BACK && (hasFullLevel || hasEnoughCapability)) {
                    // Found suitable camera - get info, open, and set up outputs
                    foundCamera = true
                    break
                }
            }
```

I plan to, in the near future update to cameraX and I would love to drop the camera1 implementation and have one unified cameraX implementation. Does anyone have experience with cameraX and whether it handles all the cases that I was previously using the camera1 fallback for? A lot of our customers are in developing markets and therefore we need to maintain support for as many older devices as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

cameraX does not have a [Camera API1](https://source.android.com/devices/camera/versioning#camera_api1) fallback. They rely on camera2 LEGACY support, but yes, the library includes many workarounds for specific problems. Please look at the list of devices they tested: https://developer.android.com/training/camerax/devices.

You don't explain what are "all the cases" you were previously using the camera1 fallback for, but if you have such list, you can go through the [release notes](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/camera) to check whether they are addressed by the current version of the library. If they are not, you are welcome to add them to the [issues list](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=618491&template=1257717).